# How to set the $PATH as used by applications in os x

Tags: macos, path, variables, environment

I'm using ant to build my project, and use the 'svnversion' executable to insert a version id into my sources for easy tracking of versions.

Running this ant file from the command line works, I've set my $PATH in .profile to include the path to svnversion and it works fine.

Now I try and run this same ant file from inside Eclipse and that does not work - the PATH in eclipse is set in another way than the PATH of the shell, I suspect this has to be set in a plist somewhere, but I don't know where.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct -- it's in the plist file

```
~/.MacOSX/environment.plist
```

This file actually contains key-value pairs for any environment variables you want to set, for the whole login session. Unlike .profile/.cshrc etc, it's available to GUI programs. Unfortunately, you can't access other environment variables (e.g., you can't use $HOME) or use any other programmatic constructs here.

*Update*: note that this is no longer supported under OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion, alas.

Answer (score 2):

A quick search at developer.apple.com turned up [Setting environment variables for user processes](http://developer.apple.com/qa/qa2001/qa1067.html).

Comment: Never thought of actually searching the apple site, I kept on trying google, lesson leared ;-)

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS X El Capitan (10.11.5), this works for me for per-user PATH entries (and other environment variables, for that matter).

- create a file `$HOME/.profile`
- set all PATH related variables in that file
- (if using bash), have your `.bash_profile` source that file, and `.bashrc`. This should be the entire contents of your `.bash_profile`:

  `# $HOME.bash_profile:
  source $HOME/.profile
  source $HOME/.bashrc`

Near as I can tell, Mac OS does not source `.bash_profile` on login for `PATH`, presumably because that is often very slow to run (initializing bash completion etc). It does seem to read `$HOME/.profile`.

You still need a `$HOME/.bash_profile` to trigger bash to read `$HOME/.bashrc`, which it otherwise wouldn't do for interactive, non-login terminals as the ones created by `Terminal.app`.