# Setting PATH environment variable in OSX permanently

Tags: macos, bash, unix, path, environment-variables

I have read several answers on how to set environment variables on OSX permanently.

First, I tried this, [How to permanently set $PATH on Linux/Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637979/how-to-permanently-set-path-on-linux) but I had an error message saying `no such file and directory`, so I thought I could try   `~/.bash_profile` instead of `~/.profile` but it did not work.

Second, I found this solution [How to set the $PATH as used by applications in os x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460835/how-to-set-the-path-as-used-by-applications-in-os-x) , which advises to make changes in

> ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist

but again I had `no such file and directory` error.

I need a way to set these variables such that it won't require setting them again and again each time I open a new terminal session.

Comment: you could just create ~/.profile most *nix systems recognize the file and use it if it exists. you might need a reboot though

Comment: ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist is deprecated.

Answer (score 436, accepted):

You have to add it to `/etc/paths`.

Reference (which works for me) : [Here](http://architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/#.Uydjga1dXDg)

Comment: This is the only solution that works on El Capitan.  Better than modifying `.bash_profile` and `.profile`.

Comment: Upvoted the answer for the reference added which explains how to remove elements from path (in the comments) too.

Comment: This worked in EL Capitan. Close all the terminals and open a new terminal to check echo $PATH.

Comment: Do not forget to 'restart' your terminal.

Comment: Works fine on macOS Catalina as well. Restart the terminal once the changes are made.

Comment: Worked great, however I feel the steps should be copied  to the answer here on SO

Comment: Works on a new tab of the Terminal after saving the /etc/paths file. Doesn't really require a restart of the Terminal.

Answer (score 66):

I've found that there are some files that may affect the `$PATH` variable in macOS (works for me, 10.11 El Capitan), listed below:

1. As the top voted answer said, `vi /etc/paths`, which is recommended from my point of view.
2. Also don't forget the `/etc/paths.d` directory, which contains files may affect the `$PATH` variable, set the `git` and `mono-command` path in my case. You can `ls -l /etc/paths.d` to list items and `rm /etc/paths.d/path_you_dislike` to remove items.
3. If you're using a "bash" environment (the default `Terminal.app`, for example), you should check out `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`. There may be not that file yet, but these two files have effects on the `$PATH`.
4. If you're using a "zsh" environment ([Oh-My-Zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh), for example), you should check out `~./zshrc` instead of `~/.bash*` thing.

And **don't forget to restart all the terminal windows, then `echo $PATH`**. The `$PATH` string will be `PATH_SET_IN_3&4:PATH_SET_IN_1:PATH_SET_IN_2`.

Noticed that the first two ways (`/etc/paths` and `/etc/path.d`) is in `/` directory which will affect all the accounts in your computer while the last two ways (`~/.bash*` or `~/.zsh*`) is in `~/` directory (aka, `/Users/yourusername/`) which will only affect your account settings.

Read more: [Mac OS X: Set / Change $PATH Variable - nixCraft](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appleosx-bash-unix-change-set-path-environment-variable/)

Comment: I quite like editing .bash_profile in some cases, because then if you had two user accounts on your machine, you could add scripts just for one of them in e.g. ~/dev/scripts

Comment: what i did not realize was that i was using zsh instead of bash. thanks!

Comment: Just in case, it's prudent NOT "to restart [ALL] the terminal windows"  until you are sure there is absolutely nothing broken.  You may observe weird new behaviour and having one terminal window with the older environment can help figure it out.

Answer (score 37):

For a new path to be added to PATH environment variable in MacOS just create a new file under `/etc/paths.d` directory and add write path to be set in the file. Restart the terminal. You can check with `echo $PATH` at the prompt to confirm if the path was added to the environment variable.

For example: to add a new path `/usr/local/sbin` to the `PATH` variable:

```
cd /etc/paths.d
sudo vi newfile
```

Add the path to the `newfile` and save it.

Restart the terminal and type `echo $PATH` to confirm

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer is getting downvoted. It seems like a reasonable and sane way to organize path variables. I have used paths.d to create individual files for every non-standard path variable.

Comment: How to save file, which key to press?

Comment: To save in terminal follow - https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-vim-save-and-quit-command/

Comment: yea, to save file and quit, I just use `Esc`, followed by `:wq` and `Enter`

Answer (score 28):

You can open any of the following files:

- `/etc/profile`
- `~/.bash_profile`
- `~/.bash_login`   (if `.bash_profile` does not exist)
- `~/.profile`      (if `.bash_login` does not exist)

And add:

```
export PATH="$PATH:your/new/path/here"
```

Answer (score 24):

If you are using zsh do the following.

1. Open .zshrc file `nano $HOME/.zshrc`
2. You will see the commented $PATH variable here

   `# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.`

   `# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/...`
3. Remove the comment symbol(#) and append your new path using a separator(:) like this.

> export
> PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:**/Users/ebin/Documents/Softwares/mongoDB/bin**:$PATH

4. Activate the change `source $HOME/.zshrc`

You're done !!!

Comment: finally worked on Apple Sillicon M2 Mac Air after hours of trying. Had to install oh-my-zsh to get the .zshrc file in home, afterwards did what you have suggested. Thank You.

Answer (score 16):

```
sudo nano /etc/paths
```

now find the path of command i am giving an example of setting path for flutter.

```
/Users/username/development/flutter/bin
```

now cntrol+x and then y . reopen the terminal and check.

Answer (score 15):

You could also add this

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

to `~/.bash_profile`, then create `~/.bashrc` where you can just add more paths to PATH. An example with `.`

```
export PATH=$PATH:.
```

Comment: Thank you. I used the previous solution, but if I apply this method, will it mean that I can also set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH variables as permanent?

Comment: Yes you should be able to. If you want to see the changes, close your terminal and reopen it, or type `. ~/.bashrc`

Comment: I add the code above to `. ~/.bash_profile`, then reopen the terminal and type `. ~/.bashrc`, but it says no such file or directory?

Comment: You need to create it. The above lines tells your  `.bash_profile` to load `.bashrc` if it exists. Then in the blank `.bashrc`, you can add anything you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I know I am asking too much, but do you know a link where it is properly stated how to create `.bashrc`? I could not manage to find a good one.

Comment: Its just a normal text file. Just open a text file and save it as `.bashrc` and put it in your home directory.

Comment: The usual place for additional PATH definitions is `~/,bash_profile`.  Therefore you could and should insert the `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin` directly to that file.  Adding the actual directory (AKA `.`) is in general no good idea.  It can cause severe harm!  If you add `.` to your PATH, than add it always as the last element (as you did :-)).

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer works. But it is missing a few important steps.

**Step 1: Update the /etc/paths file with your path**

You need sudo for this. Use the following command and add a new line with your path
`sudo vim /etc/paths`

**Step 2: Restart your terminal**

This is very important.

Comment: This answer needs more attention.
This works best with no need to make changes or creating a .profile file.
Thx

Comment: @YoracoGonzales: While I appreciate your cmt and this answer, I **do wonder** if making the PATH change permanently might inadvertently break something.  We all know there is ***much*** that is un-documented in every macOS ever released. And adding to `~/.bash_profile` requires only a `source` invocation.

Answer (score 2):

19 October 2021.

Confirming *iplus26*'s answer with one correction.

**Test environment**

**OS**: macOS 11.6 (Big Sur) x86_64

**Shell**: zsh 5.8

---

Below is the order in which the `$PATH` environment variable is modified:

1. Each line in `/etc/paths` **text file** gets appended
2. Each line in each text file inside `/etc/paths.d` **directory** gets appended
3. Finally, the `$PATH` is further modified in `~/.zshrc`

*iplus26*'s answer stated "when (you run) `echo $PATH`, The `$PATH` string will be PATH_SET_IN_3&4:PATH_SET_IN_1:PATH_SET_IN_2" but this isn't always the case. It will have to depend on what the script is doing inside `.zshrc`. E.g. If we do something like

```
PATH="/new/path:${PATH}"
```

then, the new path will be in the beginning of the path list. However, if we do something like

```
PATH="${PATH}:/new/path"
```

then, the new path will be appended at the end of the path list.

Of course, you'll have to make sure you export the modified path in the `~/.zshrc` file.

```
export PATH=$PATH
```

One handy command you could use to "pretty print" your path list is

```
print -l $path
```

This will print each path on a new line for better readability. Note `$path` is like `$PATH` except it's delimited by a single space, instead of a colon, `:`.

Hopefully this can further clarify for newcomers to this thread.

Answer (score 1):

```
launchctl setenv environmentvariablename environmentvariablevalue
```

or

```
launchctl setenv environmentvariablename `command that will generate value`
```

use proper ` and remember to restart application or terminal for the environment variable to take effect.

you can check environment variable by printenv command.

note : environment variable named path is already set by someone else so we are not appending anything to that path at all here.

Answer (score 1):

There are many places from where the value of $PATH variable is influenced.
Following is a way to add the path to it permanently in zsh:

1. Open the terminal
2. `cd /etc/paths.d`
3. Create a new file with any name. For instance you want to create a path for docker then `sudo vi dockerpath`
4. Paste your path in this file `/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin`
5. Write and close. Press esc and `:wq`
6. Open a new terminal to check if the newly added path is present. `echo $PATH`

Answer (score 0):

For setting up path in Mac two methods can be followed.

1. Creating a file for variable name and paste the path there under
   /etc/paths.d and source the file to profile_bashrc.
2. Export path variable in `~/.profile_bashrc` as

   export VARIABLE_NAME = $(PATH_VALUE)

AND  source the the path. Its simple and stable.

You can set any `path variable` by `Mac terminal` or in `linux` also.

Answer (score 0):

shows all hidden files like .bash_profile and .zshrc
`$ ls -a`

Starting with macOS Catalina, mac uses zsh instead of bash. so by default mac uses zsh.
Check which shell running:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/usr/zsh
```

```
$ cd $HOME
$ open -e .zshrc
```

or if using vim

```
$ vi .zshrc
```

Then add it like this

```
$ export my_var="/path/where/it/exists"
$ export PATH=$PATH:/$my_var/bin
```

For example: if installed app named: myapp in /Applications
Then

```
export MYAPP_HOME=/Applications/myapp
export PATH=$PATH:$MYAPP_HOME/bin
```

or shortcut

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Applications/myapp/bin
```

TADA you set for life !!! Thank me later

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the shell you're using. If you use ZSH (the default shell for Catalina and newer systems) you should edit your .zshrc file (see more at [Adding a new entry to the PATH variable in ZSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530090/adding-a-new-entry-to-the-path-variable-in-zsh)).

If you use BASH I would edit both your .bashrc and your .bash_profile files (supplementary information under https://scriptingosx.com/2017/04/about-bash_profile-and-bashrc-on-macos/).

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS

- Set a environment variable in zsh:

  `export VARIABLE_NAME=<value>`

  **Eg:** export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql-8.3.0-macos14-arm64/bin
- Save the file and restart ur terminal

  `source ~/.zshenv`

  After executing the above restart the terminal.

  Then, run `echo $PATH` to check whether the PATH is added or not.