# “export: command not found

Tags: macos, bash, path

When I open terminal on my mac it shows

```
Last login: Sun Mar 15 22:12:02 on ttys000
-bash: “export: command not found
-bash: “export: command not found
-bash: “export: command not found
-bash: “export: command not found
```

(My echo $PATH)

```
MacBook-Air-Tim:~ timreznik$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/timreznik/bin:/usr/local/bin
MacBook-Air-Tim:~ timreznik$
```

I have already tried to edit my .bash_profile to

```
# general path munging
PATH=${PATH}:~/bin
PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/bin
```

but it still keep showing me “export: command not found when I launch terminal...

P.S. all commands seems to work but my inner perfectionist is screaming!

Comment: Do you have a .profile file as well?

Comment: Not the actual problem, but still: The tilde `~` is only expanded if it is at the beginning of a shell word, which it is not in `PATH=${PATH}:~/bin`. Rule of thumb: always use `$HOME` instead of `~` when you mean your own HOME.

Comment: See this question about setting the PATH https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465332/setting-path-environmental-variables-in-osx-permanently/22465399#22465399

Answer (score 10):

First, `export` is a shell builtin:

```
$ type export
export is a shell builtin
```

This means that `PATH` is irrelevant.

Second, the error message makes clear that the script is attempting to run the command `“export`.  There is no such command:

```
$ “export
bash: $'\342\200\234export': command not found
```

The solution is to remove the spurious character from before the string `export`.

This misspelled command is in one of the shell's initialization files.  These would include: `~/.bashrc`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile`, and any files they include.

Alternatively, the following commands will tell you which files and which lines in those files have the misspelled `export` command:

```
PS4='+ $BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO:' BASH_XTRACEFD=7 bash -xlic ""  7>trace.out
grep '“export' trace.out
```

For details on how the above works, see [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/591723/221266).

Comment: Extremely helpful! in /etc/bash.bashrc was irrelevant PATH as you said) Now my terminal is cleal. Thanx)

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, the culprit was **non-breaking space** between `export` and the name of the variable. 
To resolve the issue, just replace it with a regular space character.

Details:
I had the following in `.bash_profile`:

```
export a=foo
```

When I start new terminal, I would get

```
-bash: export a=foo: command not found
```

If we run `xxd` on the file, however, we can plainly see the problem (dots are non-printable characters:

```
$ cat .bash_profile | head -n1 | xxd
00000000: 6578 706f 7274 c2a0 613d 666f 6f       export..a=foo
```

Byte sequence `c2a0` stands for [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space#Encodings)