# Apache Maven installation issues

Tags: java, maven, terminal

(on my macbook pro) I have my download unzipped in the following folder:

> /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.9/

My JAVA_HOME is set:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME 

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home
```

But i'm having issues understanding this text from the install docs:

> Add the bin directory of the created directory apache-maven-3.3.9 to
>   the PATH environment variable

What does this mean and how do I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what the `$PATH` environment variable is?

Comment: i do not!  and i cant find any helpful references online

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465332/setting-path-environmental-variables-in-osx-permanently

Comment: @Tunaki This did the trick, thanks!  (Still kind of unclear what PATHs are and what the defaults are though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some important steps to install maven are:

**Type the following in .bash_profile**

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/{jdk_version}/Contents/Home
export M2_HOME=/Downloads/apache-maven-3.*.*/
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
alias mvn='$M2_HOME/bin/mvn'
```

Replace `apache-maven-3.*.*/` with your version of apache say, `apache-maven-3.3.9/`
Refer to [this](http://shubham-technical.blogspot.in/) link for complete installation guide. This helped me configure it and worked on my MAC. I hope it helps

Comment: thanks! it does help.  I am unclear with the last command, what exactly does "alias mvn='$M2_HOME/bin/mvn'" do?

Comment: alias mvn will assign name mvn for the command '$M2_HOME/bin/mvn so that you can later use mvn instead of whole command eg mvn install

Comment: alias enables a replacement of a word by another string. It is mainly used for abbreviating a system command, or for adding default arguments to a regularly used command

Answer (score 0):

This can help,

https://askubuntu.com/questions/275704/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables-path-and-m2-home-in-ubuntu-for-ma

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/
export JAVA_HOME

M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.0.4
export M2_HOME
M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export M2

PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$M2
export PATH

Comment: This is for Ubuntu, not a Mac.

Comment: The same applies though.