# Location of $PATH variables

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I believe I have a corrupted file in my bash unix shell on Mac OS X  (10.12.3).   Upon opening a terminal I don’t have access to bash. The only thing I can do  is run % echo $PATH which returns:

```
/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/Users/greg/mongodb/bin:/Users/g
```

I can restore access to bash using

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

After doing this and checking the $PATH variable, I see

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/Users/greg/mongodb/bin:/Users/g
```

However, if I open a new terminal window, none of the $PATH info that I just added is there.

Following this Stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465332/setting-path-environment-variable-in-osx-permanently?noredirect=1&lq=1) I'm looking at the places where these variables are supposed to be set.

Looking in /etc/paths I see the following:

```
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/Users/greg/mongodb/bin
```

A /etc/profile doesn’t exist

My ~/.bash_profile looks like this

```
export PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/Users/greg/mongodb/bin:/Users/g
reg/anaconda2/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest
/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/bin:/b
in:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Library/Framewor
ks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Applications/Visual
Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin:
```

My ~/.profile looks like this

```
export NODE_PATH="/usr/local/lib/node"
export PATH="/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Everything looks okay to me.  Does this indicate that bash is using another file to set the environment variables including $PATH info? If so, where is it located? And why don’t the $PATH variable changes I make persist?

Comment: ~/.bash_profile looks thoroughly messed up; that looks like it should all be one long line, and (as zachdb86 said) should end with `:$PATH`. But there may be other, less obvious, problems as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you export PATH in in any of your .profiles you must include $PATH, otherwise PATH will be overwritten.  You do not do that in the last export of your .profile or in your .bash_profile.

Also, I would move `NODE_PATH` as well as your first `export PATH...` into `.bash_profile` and delete that final export path.

so your export statement would look like this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:...:$PATH
```