# Updating 'pip' after configuring 'pip' to point to Homebrew's pip3 causes errors

Tags: python-3.x, pip, homebrew

After installing Python 3 using Homebrew and putting the Homebrew aliases (e.g. `pip` -> `pip3`) on my path

```
export PATH=/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH
```

and then updating pip with

```
pip3 install -U pip
```

I get errors whenever I run `pip`:

> pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pip 19.1 (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('pip==19.0.3'))

How do I configure my Homebrew Python 3 correctly with pip3 so that updates to pip (and other packages) work when the aliases provided with Homebrew's Python 3 are on my path?