# Python modules installed via Homebrew not importing in .command executable

Tags: python-3.x, macos, terminal, executable

New Python programmer here!  Following [the answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1164706/how-do-i-make-a-python-file-executable-on-macos-sierra/1164713), I tried to make an executable .py file on MacOS following these steps:

- Installed Homebrew via MacOS Terminal (`$ /usr/bin/ruby-e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`)
- Installed Python3 from Homebrew (`brew install python3`)
- Installed required modules (e.g. `python3.7 -m pip install pyfiglet`)

Then, I created a simple `hello_world.py` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
python import pyfiglet
print(pyfiglet.figlet_format("Hello world!"))
input("Press any key to exit.")
```

Next, following [these instructions](https://superuser.com/questions/1164706/how-do-i-make-a-python-file-executable-on-macos-sierra/1164713),

- I renamed the file from `hello_world.py` to `hello_world.command`
- From terminal, I entered `$ cd Desktop/python` to my python projects folder
- Granted permission `chmod +x hello_world.command` to the file.

This made the python script executable, and double-clicking it opened a terminal window. However, I get the traceback `ImportError: No module named pyfiglet`.

I have confirmed pyfiglet is installed and works successfully when I paste the code directly into terminal using python3.7. Anyone know why the .command executable doesn't work? I followed these steps to the letter as described in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1164706/how-do-i-make-a-python-file-executable-on-macos-sierra/1164713). Thanks for your help!

Comment: I suspect you are picking up the wrong version of python.  Either change the shebang of the script to `#!/usr/local/bin/python3` or set the Homebrew `python3` as [the default for the system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49704364/make-python3-as-my-default-python-on-mac).

Comment: This worked! Thank you!