# How to use Python 3 in Sublime Text when it still runs Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, sublimetext3

I'm trying to run Python in Sublime but I get a syntax error because it's running Python 2.7.

I tried to create a new build with

```
{
  "cmd": ["/usr/bin/python3", "-u", "$file"],
  "file_regex": "^ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
  "selector": "source.python"
```

but that isn't working either. I made a new Python file with

```
import sys
print("Sublime is using: ", sys.version)
```

and I get

```
('Sublime is using: ', '2.7.16 (default, Oct 16 2019, 00:35:27) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)]')
```

I ran `whereis python3` in the terminal and nothing returned. When I did `whereis python` I got `usr/bin/python`. When I did `which python 3`, I got `/usr/bin/python`.

I have no idea what to do to fix this.

Comment: Did you mean to have a space in `which python 3`? For me, `which` ignores the `3` and just prints the path to python2.

Comment: yes, you're correct. the path is then ```/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3```. however, my issue remains with sublime

Comment: Does `/usr/bin/python3` exist?

Comment: that's the thing. when i type ```whereis python3``` in terminal, nothing shows up and i'm not sure why or how to fix it

Comment: Wait, in comment #2 I thought you said running `where python3` returns a path? Or does it return nothing?

Comment: no that's if i do ```whichis``` not ```whereis```

Comment: i should definitely be seeing some kind of path like ```/usr/bin/python``` (which i get if i do just ```whereis python``` or something

Comment: Here's someone with a similar problem, I think you may need to add your python directory to your path, and perhaps create /usr/bin/python3 as a symlink to your python3 binary location.

Comment: Oops, forgot the link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49704364/make-python3-as-my-default-python-on-mac