# Mac: Can installing Python wrong break other codes etc.?

Tags: macos, python-install

Can installing Python 3 wrong break other codes, applications etc. in Mac; or can I just install how I want? Cause I code in Python 3 and my Mac's built-in is 2.7

(By "how i want", I mean can any method work without any problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply install a Python3 version. If you use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/index_de) you can easy install a version with the following command:

```sh
brew install python3
```

After the installation you can check your currently python version:

```sh
python3 --version
```

At the end you can still run python scripts with Python2 by simply typing `python`.

Comment: I thought `brew install python` symlinks `python3` to `python`, does it? And will installing Python from its website do the same thing?

Comment: Yes this command do the symlink ([another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49711594/10951752)). So if you want to use the two versions you must install python3 explicitly. I have had good experience with installing the two versions, so you can quickly switch to the other version. I have never had problems with it. But I guess it should work if you do the symlink with `brew install python`.

Comment: Can installing from its website cause a problem?

Comment: No, I didn't install it yet. I do not know how Mac works so I wanted to ask.

Comment: If you want to know more details about the python3 installation on a mac with preinstalled python 2.7, I find a [nice description](https://medium.com/@rajputankit22/install-python3-in-macos-high-sierra-675d58913e6b).