# How do I change default python to 2.7 on Mac Catalina?

Tags: python, macos, cocos2d-x

Python 2.7 is no longer available on Mac Catalina, but I need it to be my default python to get Cocos Creator to build iOS apps correctly. I tried installing Python, and setting the alias as follows, but while typing `python` correctly runs python 2.7 on the terminal, it reverts to python 3.8.5 the moment I close the terminal (and Cocos still doesnt build correctly). My python 3 is installed using anaconda

Is there a way to make python 2.7 default on Catalina?

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49704364/make-python3-as-my-default-python-on-mac
Open Terminal
cd
nano ~/.bashrc
alias python=python2 (Add this line on top of .bashrc file)
Press ctr+o (To save the file)
Press Enter
Press ctr+x (To exit the file)
source ~/.bashrc OR . ~/.bashrc (To refresh the bashrc file)
```

Comment: I think general best practice is not to mess with the OS X-supplied Python installation, but to install your preferred version in parallel.

Comment: Don't modify default system Python. Use a virtualenv to build your project code

Comment: According to this comment, Python seems to have been removed for Javascript https://github.com/cocos-creator/engine/issues/4608#issuecomment-701112851

Comment: @OneCricketeer Unfortunately that's only for Cocos 3.0, which is leading edge, and Cocos 2.x are all still relying on Python 2.7.

Comment: I created a virtualenv in python 2.7, but it is still relying on python 3. So I figured, maybe I could change the default python to force it to use 2.7

Comment: Is there something in the experimental version that doesn't work for building your apps? I can't speak for cocos, but if you created the environment from your conda/Python3 installation, it wouldn't be a Python2 executable... Generally, I use pyenv to manage all Python versions. I also saw mentioned in the github issues that cocos should have an embedded Python that it uses rather than the system one

Comment: Yeah, cocos 3.0 is a major change as they changed the whole interface to support 3D, and our team prefers not to migrate so soon unless absolutely necessary. I guess I will try to mess around more and see if I can get python 2.7 to work

Comment: Are you sure python 2.7 is not available on Catalina ? Even on Big Sur, `/usr/bin/python -V` gives `2.7.16`

Comment: Hmm, I think it's more that the default python is set to python 3 and not 2 from catalina onwards, which is affecting the build process of the game engine i'm using.