# Inconsistent python3 and pip3 on OSX

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, homebrew

I cannot figure out how to get the correct version of pip3 on my Mac as the default. I installed and use Python3 via brew:

```
❯ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
❯ ls -l /usr/local/bin/python3
<ELIDED> /usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/bin/python3
```

but pip3 defaults to what looks like the Mac default Python:

```
❯ pip3 --version
pip 20.2.3 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related to [Make python3 as my default python on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49704364/make-python3-as-my-default-python-on-mac?rq=1).

It is necessary to add the path to the additional tools. e.g., in `~/.zshrc` add:

```
export PYTHON_HOME=$(brew --prefix)/opt/python/libexec

export PATH=$PYTHON_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

However, the following will **not** work:

```
export PYTHON_HOME=$(brew --prefix)/opt/python/libexec/bin 
export PATH=$PYTHON_HOME:$PATH
```

For some reason, part of the path will get cannibalized.

Answer (score 0):

On linux you have the `update-alternatives` command, I don't know if you have it on OSX.

Otherwise You can create a symbolic link.

Or use `python -m pip`

Answer (score 0):

Try running these at startup in terminal before you run python:

```
alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3
alias pip=/usr/local/bin/pip3
```