# Swiftlint autocorrect command not working

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, swiftlint

I have installed swiftlint using cocoapods and it is working properly

But when I am trying to use `swiftlint autocorrect` command in the terminal, it is giving below error

```
-bash: swiftlint: command not found
```

Should I need to do any other setup to make the command work in Terminal?

Note: Cant use the SwiftLint package due to some restriction on Mac.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pods are installed in a folder local to your project, not in any global folder that would already be defined in the terminals $PATH variable, so the terminal is unable to find the script.

There are a few options, but it mostly comes down to being more specific about where the executable is, presuming (for example) your project folder is located at `/Users/John/Documents/MyiOsProject/`

The pods are likely installed in Pods/SwiftLint/bin

so you should be able to run `/Users/John/Documents/MyiOsProject/Pods/SwiftLint/bin/swiftlint autocorrect`

This can obviously get tedious very quickly, so just alias it. (Another option would be a Symlink)

open up the file `~/.bashrc` for editing and add

```
alias swiftlint='/Users/John/Documents/MyiOsProject/Pods/SwiftLint/bin/swiftlint'
```

then you should be able to just type `swiftlint autocorrect`.

Note: I dont know your exact paths, so you may need to make some minor changes.

Comment: Thanks, in my case it worked in this way (without bin folder): /Users/yaircarreno/Documents/MyiOsProject/Pods/SwiftLint/swiftlint lint

Answer (score 1):

Installing swiftlint as a cocoapod does not modify the $PATH variable to include the path to the swiftlint command. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465332/setting-path-environment-variable-in-osx-permanently) is a guide to do it.

The path to the swiftlint command is probably $HOME/Pods/SwiftLint or sth like that.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this command is renamed to:

```
swiftlint --fix
```

This command launches autocorrection successfully!