# make virtualenv with specific python version(MACOS)

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, installation

I installed brew, python3 (default and latest version) and pip3, pyenv.

TensorFlow does not support python3.7 now, so I heard that I should make a virtualenv that runs 3.6 or lower version independently.

I installed python 3.6.7 by `pyenv install 3.6.7` but can't make `virtualenv -p 3.6.7 (mydir)` because 3.6.7 is not in the `PATH` (`usr/local/bin`).

How can I update my `PATH`?

Comment: Do you mean `usr/local/bin` in some local directory (your home directory, perhaps?) or the absolute directory `/usr/local/bin`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the executable to be on the PATH.  Assuming you want `/usr/local/bin/python3.6.7` to be used in the virtual environment,

```
virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3.6.7 mydir
```

Updating your `PATH` is easy:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

This will only update it in your current session; you might want to add this to your shell's startup files to make it permanent.  This is a common FAQ but depends on a number of factors (your shell, etc) so google for details.  Here is one question with several popular variants in the answers: [Setting PATH environment variable in OSX permanently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465332/setting-path-environment-variable-in-osx-permanently)

Answer (score 0):

I know that this doesn't answer the question exactly, but for completeness I'd like to add an [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) solution. Provided that an Anaconda environment is present on the system, a new Python environment can be created using `conda create -n py36 python=3.6 pip`. The name `py36` can be arbitrarily chosen (could also be e.g. `myenv` or `tensorflow`), the desired Python version (in this example 3.6) is specified by `python=3.6`.

This environment can then be activated using `conda activate py36` (or whatever name you assigned in the previous step). Once the environment is active, you can install `tensorflow` via `pip`: `pip install tensorflow-gpu`. To deactivate the current environment and return to the default environment, use `conda deactivate`. In this way, you don't have to modify `PATH` variables.

See also [this documentation page](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) for more details on the Anaconda environment.

Answer (score 0):

I just set up a MacOS system that had python3.9 and I wanted to create a venv with 3.11, here's how I did it.

in terminal:

```
brew install python@3.11

python3.11 -m venv PATH_TO_YOUR_NEW_VENV
```

Cheers!