# How to open conda shell in mac

Tags: python-3.x, macos, anaconda, conda, environment

I am new to conda and mac (i mostly use Ubuntu and pip). Is there a conda shell on mac (I guess I read somewhere that there is none).

If that is the case, how am I suppose to run command like:

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

as asked here: https://github.com/datitran/face2face-demo

I opened Anaconda Navigator then > Environment > Create > import > and in Specification File gave path of above environment.yml file.

Is the above step correct? 
Is there a way to do this via shell in Mac? (I am using macOS Catalina Version 10.15.3)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I am not a Mac user, but I think you can run anaconda commands directly from the terminal, just like in Ubuntu. There's no anaconda prompt in Mac.

Comment: Well Anaconda Navigator is installed but when I run it from shell it says  zsh: command not found: conda. How can I fix that?

Comment: This answer is right, `anaconda prompt` exists in windows, not on Mac or Ubuntu. As to your error, you must have said `no` during the installation if `conda` should be added to path. To fix, see the [FAQ](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/faq/#installing-anaconda):  In order to initialize after the installation process is done, first run `source <path to conda>/bin/activate` and then run `conda init`

Comment: try adding the following to your bashrc file :  export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 16):

I was having the same problem. I opened the Anaconda Navigator program. I clicked on "Environments." Under the working environment, I clicked the right arrow and one of the options was "Open Terminal." When the terminal opened using this sequence, I was able to use the conda commands. Like you I am using Mac OS Catalina.

Comment: I had a similar issue as my terminal was zsh instead of bash. Changing the ~/.zshrc instead of bash_profile helped. Credit to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465332/setting-path-environment-variable-in-osx-permanently).

Answer (score 7):

if in case you have clicked `no` during `conda` installation when it asked if it should be added to path or you just can't access it on your terminal for any other reason:

Run this `conda update anaconda-navigator` in your terminal.

But most likely it won't work because you don't have access of `conda` in your shell. What you have to do is run one at time the following steps in your terminal.

1st:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

2nd:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

3rd:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Then try:

```
conda
```

And finally make sure you exited your anaconda navigator, then run this:

```
conda update anaconda-navigator
```

This should do it, but if in case don't work out try to install `homebrew` in your Mac then repeat the steps.

Answer (score 1):

On installing anaconda on mac it may install conda in the zsh shell. So you may want to test starting the zsh.

```
$ zsh
```

and it should start the terminal with the (base)

```
(base)$ conda --version
```

Never hurts to double check.