# Define Stata path at PHP runtime

Tags: php, command-line-interface, stata

Our app runs Stata CLI via PHP on different environments but we are having a hard time determining the path of the executable on different environments.

On a Mac using `stata-mp` works, while on a different Mac we have to use `/usr/local/bin/stata-mp`; on the Linux machine instead we need `/usr/local/stata/stata-mp`.
Only the Linux environment used to be different than Mac, but now for some reason we can’t figure out also the Macs are different. The odd thing is that on Terminal/Shell `stata-mp` still works for both Macs AND the Linux server...

This is essentially the PHP code we use to execute our Stata script:

```php
$return = exec(static::STATA . " -e do script.do ", $output, $result);
```

How can we correctly define the Stata path at runtime?

Using Stata MP v16.1

Answer (score 0):

Normally is associated with your `$PATH` variable.

Try to do this:

```
$ php -a
$ var_dump($GLOBALS);
```

This will output your `$GLOBALS` environment on your shell. So you need to find a line with this:

```
["PATH"]=>
      string(168) "/home/william/.nvm/versions/node/v14.2.0/bin:/home/william/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
```

This config will show where your `php-cli` will search to execute your command.

Now, try to search where your `stata-mp` is located with this command:

```
whereis vim
```

And check if your `PATH` contains the path of your command. If does not, you can put on your `.bashrc` to your script understand on the next file read or, you can set on your script call. (It depends on your shell but, in Mac, you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465332/setting-path-environment-variable-in-osx-permanently) about the `PATH` env.

Comment: thanks @william, but I would expect STATA to have a default path I could use, maybe depending on the OS type (I used `PHP_OS_FAMILY` so far) or something, so I could not depend on PATH, which kinda depends on the actual machine. Does that makes sense?

Comment: This `PATH` is got from the `$PATH` of your OS shell so, the PHP will already get from your OS. Try to open the terminal and execute the same line that you're trying on your execute in PHP and see if it works, probably, where the PHP script don't run, you will cannot call the stata from shell already.

Comment: as I mentioned, in shell/terminal `stata-mp` works on all the environments, but when executing the commands via PHP the same Sata command is not found.
It seems that the shell/terminal environment is not the same as the PHP environment, so the `PATH` value is different, for some reason

Comment: Could be the user that you're using (if you installed STATA only on your user and executes the PHP with another user, the another user could not "see" the stata. In the past I had some issues with this using CPLEX. Installed globally and everything fine