# Pandas module cannot be imported

Tags: python, pandas, installation

I recently setup python on my new computer.

I installed all the modules but for whatever reason the pandas module is not working.

I keep getting this error which will not go away no matter what i do.

[image]

I have tried the following:

1. pip install python
2. pip install wheel
3. I have checked and confirmed that pandas 1.4.2 has been installed

Any help will be greatly appriciated.

Thanks

Comment: It is most likely a versioning/alias problem. Make sure to install pandas with pip that is associated with your python executable. run something like `python -m pip install pandas` if `python` is what you use to run your script.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Note that `pip install python` doesn't make sense (since pip already requires Python to run), and "I have checked and confirmed that pandas 1.4.2 has been installed": how?

Comment: Please don't use images of code or traceback: they are not searchable or copy-pasteable.

Comment: Please include the full traceback: there is no actual error listed in the currently shown traceback.

Answer (score -1):

Best to check if pip is installing the packages on the same path, as python is using to run.

[Find location of python package installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269795/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-python-module-sources).

If on Mac; go to terminal and type `echo $PATH` to check if this location is on your `$PATH` variable.

If this is not the case: [add python package location to path variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465332/setting-path-environment-variable-in-osx-permanently).