# DBT command not working MacBook M1 but dbt bigQuery Power User works just fine

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-bigquery, pip, dbt

I installed dbt-core and dbt-bigquery using pip install on my MacBook M1.
So far so good. In Visual Studio Code the dbt environment runs through the dbt big Query Power User plug in just fine.
In the bar below I can also see that the dbt version 1.1.1 is installed.

However, if i want to type dbt ... (dbt run, dbt docs generate, dbt whatever) in my command line in the terminal it says:

"command not found: dbt"

So dbt -V also doesnt work, but when i want to install it it says its already there (which is of course true since the plug in works).

Does someone know how to solve this?

Thanks!
Enjoy your day

Comment: you might wanna use the homebrew install instead of pip as well: https://docs.getdbt.com/dbt-cli/install/homebrew

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that dbt (and/or the underlying Python installation) is not on your `PATH`. You will need to add the directory where Python and/or dbt is installed to your `PATH` so that your shell knows where to look for an application called `dbt`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465332/setting-path-environment-variable-in-osx-permanently) for instructions for MacOS

Presumably in VS Code you used the "Select Python Interpreter" option, which placed the right Python on your PATH in your VS Code terminal session, but to work outside VS Code, you'll need to update your PATH using one of the methods above.