# How to use radian on Mac OS X

Tags: python, r

I would like to use the R console through `radian`. I thought the way to do this is to install the radian package, and then, typing `radian` would start R through radian, per the instructions on the radian [README](https://github.com/randy3k/radian/blob/master/README.md):

```
# install released version
pip3 install -U radian
# to run radian
radian
```

But, when I try to "launch" radian, I get a `-bash: radian: command not found` message.

My session information is summarized in this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/khanna7/8b3bccf0e659db83bfc7e221b12903d5).

My question is, how do I correctly install `radian` so I can use its console for R?

Comment: Sorry, what do you need help with exactly? Like, do you know how to troubleshoot this? Did you see that warning where it says `pygmentize` is being installed in a directory that's not in the `PATH`? That might be related. Please read [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask). You can [edit] to clarify.

Comment: This may have more to do with the fruit than the programs involved. https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks @wjandrea. I have edited my post to spell out my question a bit more clearly. Does this help?

Comment: @dapple-putt-poultry Yeah, that helps a lot! I think you installed it correctly, but based on the `pygmentize` warning I mentioned, it's not installed in the `PATH`. In that case, check out this question: [Setting PATH environment variable in OSX permanently](/q/22465332/4518341)

Comment: Thanks @wjandrea! I added the `'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin'` to PATH and radian works now. Thanks much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting PATH environment variable in OSX permanently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465332/setting-path-environment-variable-in-osx-permanently)