# Terminal not using newest bash_profile configuration

Tags: java, bash, maven, terminal

I was trying to set up the `mvn` command, I downloaded maven on the official Apache website and wrote `export M2_HOME="/Users/Bohan/apache-maven-3.9.0" PATH="${M2_HOME}/bin:${PATH}" export PATH` in the bash_profile. Then I tried command `mvn -version` to see if it works, it doesn't and shows `Command not found 'mvn'`. I searched and it says i need to type `source .bash_profile` to update the commands, then it works. Then I found out I have to type `source .bash_profile` every time I use a maven command.

I was expecting that once I configure the bash_profile and update the commands, it will work afterwards. It doesn't in fact I need to update the commands every time I use it. I tried restarting my computer. Closing terminal and reopening it which both didn't work. Same thing resulted, I need to update the commands every time. All answers were appreciated.

Edit: I was using MacOS, and i am not using Ubuntu(I will look into Ubuntu and SDKMAN.)

Edit 2: Thanks to Dan_Maff for pointing out I should change my bash_profile to bash. It was fixed but I'm curious why does it work?

Edit 3: Now I'm using it in IntelliJ Idea and it seems like the same problem...

Comment: (1) In Ubuntu, the configuration file I usually modify is `~/.bashrc` (2)  What operating system do you use? (3) Have you considered using SDKMAN? After installing SDKMAN, you can install JDK, Maven, Gradle through SDKMAN.

Comment: Did you change your macOS default shell to `bash`? It normally uses zsh as far as I know.
If you didn't change to bash, you should configure zsh instead.

Answer (score 0):

according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465332/setting-path-environment-variable-in-osx-permanently), you can add a permanent path to `$PATH` using this command (on MacOS):

```
sudo -s 'echo "/Users/Bohan/apache-maven-3.9.0" > /etc/paths.d/mvn'
```

and according [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/672650), you can set any environment variable globally using this command:

```
sudo launchctl setenv M2_HOME "/Users/Bohan/apache-maven-3.9.0"
```