# How do I make the 'pub' command available in the terminal?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

Install `dart` according to the tutorial:

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
 sudo sh -c 'wget -qO- https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -'
 sudo sh -c 'wget -qO- https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian/dart_stable.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dart_stable.list'
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install dart
```

After that I am already offered to use `pub`, for example

```
pub global activate aqueduct
```

however there is no such command

```
Command 'pub' not found, did you mean:...
```

But if in VS Code to create in an any folder a `pubspec.yaml` and to register in it dependences, at file saving these dependences are installed, and in a pop-up window write

```
pub get: running
```

How do I install `pub` so that I can run this command manually in the terminal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the $PATH as used by applications in os x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460835/how-to-set-the-path-as-used-by-applications-in-os-x)

Comment: Have you tried restart your terminal?